# How can I use punycode / special character in a subdomain in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm in Apache and I want to use ☎ instead of www. ie, ☎.top.tld. Most importantly, I want it to stay the original special character. Instead of getting {whatiwant}.top.tld I am getting the punycode followed by a dot and then the hostname. xn--y3h.top.tld instead of ☎.top.tld.

The first thing I did was set a wildcard DNS entry on the domain itself. Anything with a dot and then my domain works perfectly UNLESS it is a ☎. When I type that in, the browser address bar displays the punycode like so: xn--y3h.mydomain.tld.

Seriously stuck here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with Apache? You're clearly having a problem with your browser.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Until your comment, I had no idea that it was the browser doing the redirection, or that browsers did that. 
I am surprised that these same browser security features exist for subdomains as well but... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out, this is not changed on the server side, it's the browsers that do that.
Generally this is done to defend against [IDN homograph attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack#Defending_against_the_attack).
There is nothing you can do.
Depending on the TLD and browser there may be some exceptions, see the link above.
But those will be ever evolving and it doesn't make sense to explain them in detail here.